# Java IO -- closing input streams

Tags: java, java-io

If

```
FileInputStream fileIS = new FileInputStream(filePathStr);
DataInputStream dataIS = new DataInputStream(fileIS);
```

**does closing fileIS automatically close dataIS** since dataIS is propagated fileIS or should dataIS also be closed separately?

Thanks

Comment: I think this would be a good interview question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If given choice, you should close only the `DataInputStream`. More generally, always close the outermost wrapper stream. The closing will propagate inwards and this is the only way to generally ensure correct behavior.

However, if you close the underlying `FileInputStream`, that will also be enough because the `DataInputStream` doesn't by itself acquire any system resources.

The most direct answer to your question: no, closing the underlying stream **does not** close the wrapper stream, but in practice that is irrelevant from the perspective of system resource leaks. Only the stream at the bottom is coupled to the actual system resource.

Comment: how about if if create BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dataIS));  will closing br take care of closing dataIS?  i am asking this because BufferedReader is not an InputStream

Comment: @foampile it will close the readers and stream. Note: you should never mix binary (DataInputStream) and text (BufferedReader) as this can lead to confusion.

Comment: Same thing applies. All the `java.io` stream wrappers work the same way, and not only those. Every well-behaved wrapper you'll ever encounter in practice works like that.

Answer (score 2):

The reverse should be done. Since the DataInputStream wraps the FileInputStream, you should close it, which would also close the FileInputStream.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation will take care of closing the inner streams. Close the outter most stream, otherwise you can get problems when using an e.g. BufferedOutputStream and you close the OutputStream first - the data remaining within the buffer cannot be written and is lost!

Answer (score 0):

DataInputStream extends FilterInputStream and does not itself implement close() at all, so it is inherited. The behaviour you are asking about is explicitly specified in the contract for FilterInputStream.close(), which DataInputStream therefore must obey, as must all other derived classes of FilterInputStream. Similarly for derived classes of FilterOutputStream, FilterReader, and FilterWriter.